# I don't understand some syntax in Dispatcher.js in Flux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dispatcher, flux

While reading code on Flux, I found some lines I don't understand.

Source: https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/src/Dispatcher.js

1. On line 109, the angle brackets

   ```
   class Dispatcher<TPayload>
   ```
2. On line 110-115, the whole block doesn't look like javascript.

   ```
   _callbacks: {[key: DispatchToken]: (payload: TPayload) => void};
   _isDispatching: boolean;
   _isHandled: {[key: DispatchToken]: boolean};
   _isPending: {[key: DispatchToken]: boolean};
   _lastID: number;
   _pendingPayload: TPayload;
   ```
3. On line 138, the function with `: void` before curly braces.

   ```
   unregister(id: DispatchToken): void {
   ...}
   ```

I thing it is because of some kind of js library. But I'm not sure. The only trace I can find is that invariant is required for this js file. but I can't find the code or documents of invariant.

Comment: 1. http://flowtype.org/ (flow) 2. flow + es6 arrow function + es6 dynamic property name 3. flow

Comment: This better-resembles TypeScript than pure ECMAScript 6, however no part of Flux's build process references TypeScript. They are using a version of Gulp that adds early support for many ES6 features, but this stumps me, I'll admit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't *just* Javascript (check out [this line](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/src/Dispatcher.js#L10)), it's [flow](http://flowtype.org/).

Flow adds static type checking to Javascript code.

Specifically:

1. http://flowtype.org/docs/classes.html#polymorphic-classes
2. It's a mix of es6 and Flow syntax
3. http://flowtype.org/docs/functions.html#type-annotating-functions

Comment: Thank you very much!
But could you give me some link of invariant? I just can't find any docs about it. Thanks again!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "invariant is required for this js file"?

Comment: I mean at the top of the file:    var invariant = require('invariant');    Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: invariant is similar to assert but only its message will be stripped in production https://www.npmjs.com/package/invariant